# Using a macro for a libraries namespace?

Tags: c++, libraries, namespace, macros

In some code bases (such as hydra, and thrust's tuple implementation) I see namespaces defined entirely with macros.   It appears the reason for this is so that you can configure the namespace to your liking.  Is this the only use case for this practice? Even so why shouldn't all libraries define a macro for the namespace?  Would it not be better to just do the following:

```
#ifndef LIB_NS
#define LIB_NS default_namespace
#endif

namespace LIB_NS{
...
}

LIB_NS::foo(...);
```

for every library I make? `ifndef` is used so that I could define the name of the symbol as a compiler option or somewhere outside of the include before hand.

**Here are the examples:**

[Thrust example](https://github.com/jaredhoberock/tuple/blob/master/include/tuple.hpp)

[Hydra repository](https://github.com/MultithreadCorner/Hydra) (can't find where they define it, but its used a lot)

Comment: I think you're going to need to make your question more specific.  `#ifndef #define` is traditionally used to make sure symbols are only defined once, and thrust [doesn't appear to use macros to define its namespaces.](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/thrust/tuple.h)  It's unclear to me what benefits your sample code provides.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  Nvidia has not maintained parity with the public Thrust repo for some time, they will soon do so.  The tuple implementation I was talking about was this one, the candidate for variadic tuple replacement https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues/524.  Also not sure why you only looked at thrust and not Hydra...

Comment: Emptying the `LIB_NS` namespace might heavily change the semantics to _anonymous namespaces_. Be aware of that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "#ifndef #define is traditionally used to make sure symbols are only defined once" exactly... not sure what your deal is with this one.  "It's unclear to me what benefits your sample code provides"  A: I'm asking you guys about that, B: configuring the namespace to your liking to avoid namespace conflicts with potential other libraries, a possibility I mentioned in my own post....

Comment: The `#define` in that Thrust example appears to be there to *provide one point of modification for the namespace name.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey Wow, that's totally different than " It appears the reason for this is so that you can configure the namespace to your liking"!

Comment: Why do you see that as different?  If I'm going to allow a user to change the namespace of my library, the best possible way to do that is to *provide one point of modification for the namespace name.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was being sarcastic...  Remember when you said "It's unclear to me what benefits your sample code provides."

Comment: I guess I'm just wondering why you consider this so profound.  There's not much to see here.  Fundamentally, you use a `#define` for the same reasons you use a constant anywhere else: to provide a single point of modification.  That's all there is to this.

Comment: Are you asking under what conditions you might want a single point of modification?

Comment: @RobertHarvey  I'm asking why I wouldn't want to do this for nearly every single library, I've not seen this in a lot of places.  It seems that namespace conflict would always be a potential issue, so why shouldn't I just use this for everything

Comment: If you saw no need for the namespace to be configurable in this way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  But when would that ever happen if I was making a library?

Comment: Your assertion that this would always be an issue seems at odds with the fact that (by your own observation) libraries seldom do this.  So the question now becomes "Why does Thrust do this?" (which is probably a good question for the folks at Thrust).

Comment: @RobertHarvey so now this is profound?...

Comment: Not to me. The easiest way to deal with this is use a namespace that is unlikely to be duplicated.

Comment: Jesus Christ man... so its not profound, but you appear to either agree that it is seldom used, but also there are some how reasons to have a library that wouldn't be namespace configurable, yet, there are no examples outside of say std libraries?

Comment: I'm getting a little beyond my pay grade here, but I noticed that the Thrust example is a C++ template.  If I were publishing or using such  a template, I think it would be very handy to be able to change the namespace, given that metaprogramming is involved.

Comment: OK, I had a little chat with someone in the C++ room about your question.  The conversation starts here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/42804272#42804272

Comment: Hydra appears to just use `namespace hydra`.

Comment: @snb: "*I'm asking why I wouldn't want to do this for nearly every single library*" I'd be more curious as to why you would *want* to. The only possible benefit I can see would be if there were two libraries that wanted to use the same namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This technique is sometimes used to handle transitive dependencies on header only libraries. It is not generally a best practice.

The problem: I am writing a C++ library. I put all of my declarations into a `namespace foo { ... }`. So users of my library can avoid that namespace. But what happens when I want to use another library in my library? Let's call the second library `bar`. If I use the bar library normally, I am exposing both the `foo` and `bar` namespaces to the users. My dependency is not invisible, and could break code of my users.

If the `bar` library makes its namespace configurable, I can avoid that by moving it into a `foo::detail::bar` namespace.

At first, it might seem like I could simply include a header within a namespace:

```
namespace foo { namespace detail {
#include <bar.h>
} }
```

However, headers are generally written to assume that they are included at the top-level. In particular, expect this to break the standard library as used through that header. This will also fail if bar is not a header-only library, because the object code will be compiled into a different namespace.

Using macros is the preferable solution. A single namespace macro that takes values such as `foo::detail` is insufficient prior to C++17, so that separate macros for declaration start/end and the actual namespace are necessary. E.g. see [this example in Hydra](https://github.com/MultithreadCorner/Hydra/blob/v2.1.0/hydra/detail/external/thrust/detail/config.h).

However, these techniques suffer from various problems and restrictions.

- The header files typically still contain include guards, so that each compilation unit can import a library under at most one namespace. In practice, this is not a big restriction.
- If a library is imported under multiple namespaces, any objects declared by that library are duplicated. This may or may not be desired.
- If the library with variable namespaces is not a header-only library, then the object code for that library must also be compiled into the correct namespace. This requires you to define the necessary macros in your build system.

The core problem that these macros are trying to solve is that C++ does not have a proper module system. How are other languages addressing potentially clashing namespaces?

- Java has a package naming convention based on domain names, so no name clashes between organizations should arise. E.g. If you hold `example.com`, then you should put the foo library into the `com.example.foo` namespace.
- Rust and Perl have one central library index (Crates and CPAN, respectively). Just don't use any namespaces that could be reserved there. Additionally, Rust does not make the namespace of a crate visible unless you import it, whereas the C++ one-definition-rule is global.
- Python has relative imports. A well-written module does not need to know its absolute location.

Hopefully, C++ modules will adopt a reasonable solution when they finally arrive.

The tuple example you linked to is fundamentally different: the purpose of that library is to patch the standard library if it doesn't provide a tuple of its own. Here, the namespace configurability is only provided to optionally place the tuple into a different namespace.

To summarize: configurable namespaces have legitimate uses when building libraries for libraries. Most C++ code should not bother with this, especially not application code.